# Не отвести глаз или не свести глаз?

Tags: выбор-слова, глаголы

Is there any difference in meaning between these two expressions?

Comment: you can't use genitive instead of accusative in affirmative sentences, only in negative ones. It's *не отвести глаз* but *отвести глаза*.

Comment: Yes; a simple addition of “не” changes the meaning, as “не отвести глаз” can be used as a substitute for the adjective “красивый”, as in “жених — просто не отвести глаз”, “an irresistibly handsome groom”, whereas “отвести глаза” means “shift one’s gaze”.

Comment: Глаз не отвести is more often used with fronting the noun (beautiful ), the second is used mainly in imperfective не сводить глаз (to gaze ), with negative forms only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one, “отвести глаз”, has only one meaning: to look away, like in “She is so beautiful, I cannot look away from her”. Is may be used in a general description:

> Она такая красивая — глаз не отвести.

Of course, “глаз” is plural genitive, not singular nominative, because negation with transitive verbs often requires genitive case, as in French “faire qch” — “ne faire pas *de* qch”, with *de* implying genitive case).

The second one can be used in a sentence where you emphasize that looking is an action:

> Всю лекцию я не сводил с неё глаз.

Someone has been actually staring at her incessantly because he was infatuated.

However, you may put “отвести глаза” in a sentence with an action taking place:

> Он положил украденные деньги на стол и стыдливо отвёл глаза.

He looked aside because he was ashamed of what he had done.

Last but not least, simply “свести глаза” also means “свести глаза в кучу”, i.e. cross one’s eyes or impersonate someone with a squint.

> Чтобы изобразить безумного профессора, он взлохматил волосы и свёл глаза.

To sum it up, if you mean that one cannot look aside because X is beautiful, use “не отвести глаз от X”. If you intend to say that someone was gazing at X, you say “не сводил глаз с X”. If someone focused his sight on the tip of his nose to look cross-eyed, use “свести глаза”. If someone looked away, say “отвести глаза” or “отвести взгляд”.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer and especially for paraphrasing the meaning in the Russian sentences. I still have trouble understanding written Russian sometimes and it was very helpful :-)

Answer (score 5):

Both those sentences have several idiomatic meanings (some of them only in negative).

1. To revert one's eyes (both can be used in negative, only *отвести* in affirmative). In negative this means "to watch someone closely, to keep sight on someone".

> - ― Он мешал и тем, и этим, ― отводя глаза, проговорил Мышкин.
> - ― Примерно столько же, ― ответил Сторожев, не отводя глаз от Даши, которая в это время нагнулась.
> - ― Приезжает… ― повторила Тамара зло, не сводя глаз с Каландарашвили.

2. To divert one's attention, to fool (used with dative, only *отвести*):

> - Те две капли мёда, которые дольше других отводили мне глаза от жестокой истины ― любовь к семье и к писательству, которые я называл искусством, ― уже не сладки мне.
> - Они, наверно, влюблены друг в друга, хоть и отводят людям глаза, и оттого бедный Николай Сергеич сослан в кабинет.

3. To cross, squint one's eyes, to look at some direction (usually down). Only *свести* can be used:

> - Валюшок очень комично свел глаза к переносице.
> - Еще до того, как все они уставились на нее, пихая пригожего детину, который, сведя глаза, разбирал у себя на шее какие-то цепочки и шнурки, Софья Андреевна почуяла опасность.
> - Прислонясь к дереву, я с голосистых певцов невольно свел глаза на самих слушателей-наблюдателей, тот поврежденный класс полу-европейцев, к которому и я принадлежу.

4. *Не отвести глаз* as an idiomatic predicative adjective, meaning "very pretty"

> - Валькирия собрала все свои познания и стала просто красоткой, глаз не отвести.
> - Вроде лишь вчера зарозовелась, а вот уже стоят деревца нарядные, глаз не отвести
> - У нас в механическом при Жердее выбросили четыре «бромлея», этакие грохота, и установили два «краснопролетарца» ― глаз не отвести!